# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax"

Tags: php, mysql

Through the prompt method ,i'm taking the name of the person to create a table .The method is working and the name is being parsed by the php script .But no matter what ,the table is not getting created and getting the following

> ERROR: Could not able to execute CREATE TABLE kat (Item VARCHAR(50) , Quantity INTEGER, Price REAL).
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'kat (Item VARCHAR(' at line 1  "

```
echo("<script type='text/javascript'> var answer = prompt('Enter name'); </script>");
$na= "<script type='text/javascript'> document.write(answer); </script>";
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $na (Item VARCHAR(50) , Quantity INTEGER, Price REAL)"; 
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    echo "Table created successfully.";}
else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Comment: So, what does google say?

Comment: a webserver does not wait for javascript to execute in the browser, by the time the user entered anything into the prompt it has long since ended the thread

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are sending the following as the name of the table (expansion of `$na`):

`<script type='text/javascript'> document.write(answer); </script>` which shows as `kat` in your error message in the browser, but in reality is it is the Javascript code above, which produces an invalid SQL statement. `$na` should be set to something you send to the web server via GET or POST, which will be available in the `$_GET`, `$_POST`, or `$_REQUEST` variables, or in the `php://input` stream if you send it in the body of the POST request, e.g. as JSON. Another issue, but nevertheless worth mentioning - make sure to sanitize the user input to avoid the possibility of SQL-injection.

So, for example, have a POST form with a field `answer` that you send to the server, and then `$na = mysqli_escape_string($_POST["answer"]);` followed by 

`` $sql = "create table `$na` (Item VARCHAR(50) , Quantity INTEGER, Price REAL)"; ``

and the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

add your connection into `$con.`